# Varnish not making origin call for infrequently requested cache

Tags: varnish

I'm noticing this behavior on Varnish 6.5 where it's not making backend calls per the max-age cache control origin response, if the request is not frequently requested by clients.

Below's the expected behavior I see for a cache requested every 1 second. It has 20 seconds max-age cache-control header from origin:

```
Request 1:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:02:02 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 33692
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge;chrome=1
pragma:
cache-control: public, max-age=20
x-varnish: 1183681 1512819
age: 17
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes

Request 2:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:02:04 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 33692
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge;chrome=1
pragma:
cache-control: public, max-age=20
x-varnish: 891620 1512819
age: 19
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes

Request 3:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:02:05 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 33692
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge;chrome=1
pragma:
cache-control: public, max-age=20
x-varnish: 1183687 1512819
age: 20
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes

Request 4:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:02:06 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 33692
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge;chrome=1
pragma:
cache-control: public, max-age=20
x-varnish: 854039 1183688
age: 1
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes
```

You can see the Request #4 above makes a new origin request with the cache request id being 1183688.

Now if I wait a long while and make that same request, the cache age is pretty old and varnish does not make an origin request to cache a fresh object:

```
Request 5 after a while:
HTTP/2 200
date: Tue, 20 Jul 2021 02:10:08 GMT
content-type: application/json
content-length: 33692
server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
x-ua-compatible: IE=edge;chrome=1
pragma:
cache-control: public, max-age=20
x-varnish: 1512998 1183688
age: 482
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
vary: Accept-Encoding
x-cache: HIT
accept-ranges: bytes
```

I suppose I could start adding the `Expires` header from origin, but looking for explanation why varnish behaves this way if the request is infrequent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TTL header precedence in Varnish

Varnish does check the `max-age` directive, but there might be other factors can cause the TTL to be an unexpected value.

Here's the TTL precedence:

1. The `Cache-Control` header's `s-maxage` directive is checked.
2. When there's no `s-maxage`, Varnish will look for `max-age` to set its *TTL*.
3. When there's no `Cache-Control` header being returned, Varnish will use the `Expires` header to set its *TTL*.
4. When none of the above apply, Varnish will use the `default_ttl` runtime parameter as the *TTL* value. Its default value is *120 seconds*.
5. Only then will Varnish enter `vcl_backend_response`, letting you change the *TTL*.
6. Any *TTL* being set in *VCL* using `set beresp.ttl` will get the upper hand, regardless of any other value being set via response headers.

### Your specific situation

The best way to figure out what's going on is by running `varnishlog` and adding a filter for the URL you want to track.

Here's an example for the homepage:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

The output will be extremely verbose, but will contain all the info you need.

Tags that are of particular interest are:

- `TTL` see https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.5/reference/vsl.html#varnish-shared-memory-logging
- `BerespHeader` (specifically the `Cache-Control` backend response header)
- `RespHeader` (specifically the `Cache-Control` response header)

Please also have a look at your VCL and check whether or not the TTL is changed by `set beresp.ttl =`.

### What do I need to help you

In summary, if you want further assistance, please provide your full VCL, as well as a `varnishlog` extract for the transactions that is giving you to unexpected behavior.

Based on that information, we'll have a pretty good idea what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much replying to this question. varnishlog definitely helped in debugging this issue. At Request 5, following the max-age expiration, the backend request was indeed made asynchronously. 

Reason I wasn't seeing the age update was because we have a 120m grace period setting. Request 6 would have shown an updated age.

The other place I messed up was, I thought I was tailing comprehensive origin logs and seeing no origin requests. That was an error on my part that led to asking this question. My apologies.